# shellcode is executed in two loops instead of one

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64, shellcode

i am succesfully build up my shellcode.

```
[BITS 64]

segment .text
    global _start

_start: jmp call

back:   lea rsi, [rsp]
    mov rdi, [rsi]
    xor rax, rax
    push rax
    lea rdx, [rsp]
    mov al, 0x3b
    syscall
call:   call back
    db "/bin/sh",0
```

But there is something mysterious about the code execution. I still can not figure it out whats the issue and maybe someone is able to help.

When i am debugging the code with radare2 the whole process of setting the arguments and syscalling is executed twice. I have no idea whats wrong with it. The registers, rip and so on looks good. In the end, the shell pops after the second loop. But for execution on stack it is a pain in the ass, because my /bin/sh screwed up in the second loop.

The first syscall returns -14 (BAD ADRESS)

I tried already some code variations and RTFM. Help

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Interesting; usually the jmp/call trick is done with a `pop` to get the address into a register, but here you actually are trying to build a pointer array on the stack instead of just using argv=envp=0.

Comment: Yes, i wanted to do it myself from scratch and this was the result. Maybe these extra bytes due to clean pointer arrangements, gives some extra "umpf" when it is not /bin/sh which is desired?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, the `argv` array is malformed.
You set that parameter to an address on the stack but you didn't put a null pointer to terminate it.

This is the (lower portion of) stack when the first instruction of `_start` is executed:

```
...
0
argN
...
arg0
argc <-- rsp
```

Note that these are the arguments of *your* program. Also note that `<--` means "points to" (or: contains the address of).

When `back` is called the stack is:

```
...
0
argN
...
arg0
count
ptr to shell path <-- rsp
```

After the `lea`s (by the way, `lea` with such a trivial addressing mode is just a `mov`) and the `xor`, the stack is:

```
...
0
argN
...
arg0
count
ptr to shell path <-- rsp, rsi
                  rdi = ptr to shell path
```

Then just before the `syscall` we have:

```
...
0
argN
...
arg0
count
ptr to shell path <-- rsi
                  rdi = ptr to shell path
0                 <-- rsp, rdx
```

Then `execve` will read the executable path from `rdi` (which checks), the `envp` from `rdx` (which checks), and the `argv` from `rsi` (which fails).
The last one fails because `execve` will read up the stack from the path of the shell to the first 0, but `count` is not a valid pointer (it is probably 1).

Having the system call failed, the execution falls through to `call back`, the steps are repeated but this time the 0 from the previous iteration will correctly terminate `argv`:

```
...
0
argN
...
arg0
count
ptr to shell path
0
ptr to shell path <-- rsi
                  rdi = ptr to shell path
0                 <-- rsp, rdx
```

You can:

- Do nothing and leave it this way as a tricky way to invoke the shell (note that some value of `count` could be interpreted as a valid pointer, giving the shell an argument).
- Change the `count` into a zero. You can move `xor eax, eax` up and use `mov [rsp+8], rax`. This works in other contexts as long as you can write at `[rsp+8]`.
- Push a zero yourself. Either pop the return address in a register and then push it after pushing a zero or use an `xchg` or similar.
- Pass `argv` and `envp` as `NULL` (i.e. zero out `rsi` and `rdx`). On Linux this has the same effect as what you are already doing (passing an array with a single null pointer).
- If you want to pass your program argument to the shell, you can double pop and then push the return address or pop the return address and use a `mov` to overwrite `count`.

Comment: Wow, this is awesome. Thank you very much. I was thinking in the opposite direction of my argv and thought the 0 from envp was the final 0 for argv.

Comment: @bplinux Glad to help. It's easy to get tricked with pointers and stack :)